# Use jenkins without version control systems

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, integration

---

Hi, is possible to use Jenkins to automate unit test but without any version control system like git or svn? I have the code in local storage, in the same server of Jenkins.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-BuildsforNonSourceControlProjects)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's. But why not use a version control in the same server? It might be the best pratice, but better than nothing.